# How redirect to other view using Barcode-Scanner in Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ionic2, barcode-scanner

I need to redirect to another view when the barcode is scanned, I am using barcode-scanner in ionic 2. I tried the push method but it does not work not load the other page, I also try to pass the parameters to the other view. What am I doing wrong?

Method of first view :

```html
     async scanBarcode(){
    
    this.options = {
      prompt : 'Escanea un codigo de barra...'
    }


     this.results = await this.barcode.scan(this.options);
     this.navCtrl.push(Infoproducto,{    //this not working
          resultados: this.results 
     });
     //console.log(this.results);
  }
```

And this is the other view To which I want to redirect :

```html
   <div *ngIf="resultados">

   <p>{{results.text}}</p>
   <p>{{results.format}}</p>
   <p>{{results.cancelled}}</p>

   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work something like this:

```
this.barcodeScanner.scan().then((barcodeData) => {
    this.navCtrl.push(SomePage, {data: barcodeDate});
    }, (error) => {
      // handle error
    });
```

I've used something similar to this in the past with success.